# Is the language given by the regex (ab)* star-free?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I was reading about [star-free languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-free_language) recently and a common example of a non-star free language is the one given by (aa)*.
I was wondering if (ab)* would also work (for an alphabet of two symbols let's say).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.  $L=(ab)^*$ is [star-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-free_language).  A word is in $L$ iff

1. It starts with $a$ (or is empty)
2. It ends with $b$ (or is empty)
3. It does not contain any consecutive $a$'s
4. It does not contain any consecutive $b$'s

Each of those conditions can be represented by a star-free language.  Indeed, condition 3 is the first example given on Wikipedia of a star-free language.  Here are star-free regular expressions for each of those:

1. $(b\emptyset^c)^c$
2. $(\emptyset^c a)^c$
3. $(\emptyset^c aa \emptyset^c)^c$
4. $(\emptyset^c bb \emptyset^c)^c$

where $S^c$ denotes the complement of $S$.

Consequently,

$$L = (b\emptyset^c)^c \cap (\emptyset^c a)^c \cap (\emptyset^c aa \emptyset^c)^c \cap (\emptyset^c bb \emptyset^c)^c,$$

which is a star-free representation for $L$.  Another equivalent representation is

$$L = (b\emptyset^c |  \emptyset^c a | \emptyset^c aa \emptyset^c | \emptyset^c bb \emptyset^c)^c.$$

Comment: Very clear explanation thank you, I will explore other languages such as (ab*)*

Comment: This is why I dislike questions that ask one thing in the title and another in the body. I had to scan a couple of times to realize that "No" was answering "if (ab)* would also work [as an example of a non-star free language]" and not the title.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the four requirements in the excellent [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/161968/4287) by D.W. are in fact first-order definable. That is, they can be formulated quantifying over positions in the string and the relative order of these positions. By a result of McNaughton and Papert these are star-free.

Every regular language, including the non-star-free example $(aa)^*$, can be specified using a logic where one also is allowed to quantify over sets of positions. This is a result from [Büchi, Elgot and Trakhtenbrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCchi-Elgot-Trakhtenbrot_theorem). (Intuitively sets of positions where a finite automaton reaches a specific state.)